# Is Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS set in a different world/universe

Tags: nanoha

After watching Season 2 (Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha A) i went to watch the 3rd season (Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS), at the end of season 2 during the credit roll Nanoha, Fate and Hayate are older and Reinforce has been reborn into a small girl and in season 3 Nanoha, Fate, Hayate and Reinforce all look the same as they did at the very end of season 2 i would assume not too much time has passed since that final scene however the world seems more futuristic and the Space-Time Administration seems to operate in public.

so i am wondering, is Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS set in a different world/universe to the one Nanoha and Hayate were born in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same universe - just some 10 years later.

- Nanoha, Fate, and Hayate are all grown up. (teenagers as opposed to kids)
- Signum, Vita, Zafira, and Shamal don't age at all because they are bound to the Book of Darkness (they're not human).

Comment: is that 10 years after the the original Reinforce said goodbye or 10 years after the final credit roll where we see Reinforce reborn and Nanoha, Fate and Hayate being older

Comment: It's 10 years after the original Reinforce "dies". I'm not sure about the credit roll though. But it's definitely between the two seasons.

Comment: The ending of *Nanoha A's* was 6 years later than the actual story. *Nanoha StrikerS* was 10 years later than the actual story, therefore there is a gap of 4 years between those two (Hence, Nanoha and co. are still in school, but aren't in StrikerS).

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, it is the same universe, the same continuity.  But *StrikerS* does take place (mostly) on a different **planet**.

Nanoha and Hayate were born on Earth, which the Administration calls Non-Administered World #97. The setting of *StrikerS* (and *Vivid*) is mostly the capital of the Space-Time Administration, Midchilda, which is where Fate and Yuuno are originally from.  The epilogue of *A's* was in the last year of the girls' middle school education, on Earth; as seen in the *A's to Strikers* chapters of the *StrikerS* manga, after the end of their compulsory education, the girls all intended to move to full-time service with the Administration, and the three spent the next four years pursuing their careers there, before they were reunited under Hayate's command in Riot Force 6.